# "TRIM" in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the "state" column in the table. In this state column, when I checked the length of values, I found one cell only showing value 3 remaining all are 2. "OH" in the state column. So it may be because of the space("OH "). So I want to remove the space using the TRIM function.

[image]

Still, after running, The length shows "3" for the particular one. If trims have happened, It should be shown 2 instead of 3. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `LENGTH(TRIM(state))` if you want the length without blank spaces at the beginning or the end of `state`. Notice that `LENGTH(" OH")` is still 3, although in your `WHERE`, `LENGHT(TRIM(" OH")` = `LENGTH("OH")` and that is 2, so " OH" passes your where condition.